# Unable to receive push notifications

Tags: ios, ssl, openssl, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am following this tutorial to set up a push notifications >> http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

Yet push notifications do not come to my phone. The phone registers succesfully. The provider connects to apns succesfully and sends the message to the registered deviceToken. Yet no notification arives.

Tried to follow the tutorial for a second time from the begining and still the same result.

At third time I tested my ck.pem files like this

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert ck.pem -debug
```

And got this return.

```
Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

Searched for a while on how to resolve this, yet nothing helped. I don't know if this is why phone fails to recieve messages but it could be the case. Anybody knows how can i solve this? Or maybe other things to check ? I'v done the tutorial step by step for the third time, and don't know what to look for. APNS doesn't return any error-status after sending message.

Provider posting code in php>>

```
<?php

$deviceToken = 'c8964c75e5d404f029e2d599d094a2114d219bdb95750ae6501d6f0ce6a3c3b4';

$passphrase = 'DEADFFFF';

$message = 'Check';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

fclose($fp);
```

Application is in debug mode, server certificate is also for development
Running the code gives Message successfully delivered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything was fine! The development phone was jailbroken and it did not receive push notifications. On non jailbroken phone everything worked fine, so stay away from jailbroken phones in development! I'v spend a day figuring this out...

Answer (score 0):

For `ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195`,

- Debug build
- Development code-signing.

If you want to use production details, then use `ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195`

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, check that you're using the correct provisioning profile (with push enabled and for development). Reboot the device and try again.

Comment: Provisioning profile is correct. Tried this way, but still same result. Strangest thing is that provider connects to APNS sents message successfully (no error-status back from APNS). Yet device does not get the notification, even though it had successfully registered for notifications..